# How to go to Dalaran from Ashran?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Now that the Warlords of Draenor expansion is out, I figured out there is no direct portal at Ashran (which is the new capital right?) or at my garrison to go to Dalaran in Northrend.

What is the fastest way to get there?

Comment: Presumably you aren't a Mage?

Comment: @JonK exactly !

Comment: A simple option that I've taken: Leave your hearthstone set to the Shrine in Pandaria.  I've found having direct access to a room full of portals (plus bank and ethereals) is much better than porting to Ashran which, honestly, feels lacking compared to previous capital cities.  Once your garrison is level 3, you can get to Ashran by using your garrison hearth and jumping in the portal.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming you aren't a mage and can't teleport yourself:

The fastest way to Dalaran is to teleport yourself with one of the sixteen [rings of the Kirin Tor](http://wowpedia.org/Ring_of_the_Kirin_Tor). If you played during Wrath, you might still have one laying around in Void Storage. If not, well, they start at 6800 gold (at Exalted with the Kirin Tor). Visit [Harold Winston](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=32172)  to buy one.

You can also use [Jaina's Locket](http://www.wowhead.com/item=52251) to create a portal to Dalaran on a one hour cooldown. This can sometimes be found for 10K gold or less on the auction house, or you can run the Shadowmourne legendary quest chain and get your own.

The second fastest way is to ask in chat while in Ashran or your garrison and buy a portal to Dalaran from a mage.

If you played in the Argent Tournament, you can use their [Argent Crusader's Tabard](http://www.wowhead.com/item=46874) to teleport to the tournament grounds, and Dalaran is a short flight away.

If you're an engineer, you can use a [Wormhole Generator: Northrend](http://www.wowhead.com/item=48933) to get to Northrend, and then fly from Storm Peaks to Dalaran.

If you're a monk and can fly in Pandaria, you can take a [Zen Pilgrimage](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=126892) to the Peak of Serenity, then fly to the Shrine, then take a portal to Dalaran.

Failing the above, my suggestion would be to take the portal to Stormwind/Orgrimmar, then the portal to Pandaria, a flight to the Shrine, and then the portal to Dalaran within. This should be faster than taking a ship to Northrend as you won't have to wait for it, and the flight in Pandaria is shorter than the flight in Northrend.

Comment: As a quick note, if you have the teleports from completing the challenge modes back in MoP, you can use the Path of the Mogu King to teleport near the Shrines. It's pretty fast from there!

Answer (score 0):

I know I am bit late on this! But it is fairly easy. Go to Warspear, go to the Orgrimmar Port, and then when you get to Org, there is a Dalaran port right there.

Answer (score -1):

Not directly to Dalaran, but the tabard of the argent crusade teleports you close. And is fairly easier/cheaper than the rings :)

Comment: This was already mentioned before. I would love to hear any _new_ ideas on how to get to Dalaran quickly, though.

Comment: This does not provide anything that the much older, accepted answer provides. Please keep in mind that duplicate answers are frowned upon here and may be subject to deletion.

Answer (score -3):

There is a mage in warspear who will portal you to Dalaran

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. While this does appear to answer the question, it'd be great if you could edit this answer and give us more detail - for example, what's the mage's name?

Comment: If this is true then I'm faction changing. There's no such mage in Stormshield that I've ever seen.